# How to run a jar with a different java path using a .sh script (Openj9)

Tags: java, linux, bash

How would I go about running my Jar files to test with Openj9 in Ubuntu?
Preferably using a .sh script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

your_path_to_open_jdk_9/bin/java -jar yourJar.jar
```